# CSS Dropdown menu tutorial line25.com not working for me

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm complete newbie to web design and programming and I've been trying to make a blog page as a kind of teach myself project. I have no particular aim at this point beyond exploring features and working things out for myself so basically I'm operating from zero knowledge at this point. I found [this](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) dropdown menu tutorial with the end result purportedly [this](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html). I first tried it on my blog page project and it didn't work, so, I decided to go through the instructions line by line to replicate the effect and, hopefully, in the process, discover where I had gone wrong on my first attempt. I have followed the instructions completely down to the colours and all the styling and yet it still doesn't work for me! The menus won't drop down. 
I am using notepad++ and running the code from notepad++ on firefox. Below is my html and css file. If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong I would be greatly appreciative.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='layout.css'/>
    </head>
<nav>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>       
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}
        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }

nav ul {
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbb 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbb 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba (0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table
}

        nav ul:after {
                content: ""; clear: both; display: block
        }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradientlinear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        } 
                nav ul li:hover a{
                    color: #ff
                }
        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
        }

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
            position: relative;
        }
                nav ul ul li a {
                    padding: 15px 40px;
                    color: #fff;
                }
                        nav ul ul li a:hover {
                            background: #4b545f;
                        }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

Comment: Just a tip. white is `#fff` and not `#ff`.

Comment: Yes and don't forget to put the body tag.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is in the html code where you close the `li` tags
"tutorials" and "articles".

These are a whole element and you must not close before including the sub lists.

Here an example:

Change:

```
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The CSS isn't pretty either, there's a few missing semi-colons scattered about. But the HTML is definitely the main issue.